# how to display db context data in mvc4 view returning from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How do I display db context data in an mvc4 view?  Below is my controller code:

```
   public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {

        AuthorContext oauthorContext = new AuthorContext();
        Author oauthor = oauthorContext.Authors.Single(x => x.authorid == id);
        return View(oauthor);
    }
```

And in view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Author Detail";
}

<h2>AuthorDetail</h2>

@{
    foreach Context in 
}
```

Comment: I am not getting object oauthorcontext  @{ foreach Context in }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to display your db context data in a view is to put the data into a model or a view model, and pass that model to your view.

You have made a good start, as you're passing `Author` into your view.

If your view is strongly typed to `Author`, you should have access to `oauthor` in your view by using the `Model` object.

In your view

```
<h2>@Model.SomeAuthorProperty</h2>
```

would be an example of showing `oauthor.SomeAuthorProperty` inside a `h2` element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are missing is @model Author at the top of your view:

```
@model Author

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Author Detail";
AuthorName = Model.Name //assuming Name is a property of Author
}

<h2>@AuthorName Detail</h2>
```